# AsyncSocket connection works only at home network

Tags: ios, cocoa, asyncsocket, cocoaasyncsocket

I am using AsyncSocket to make my iPhone send data to my Mac. Mac works as a server to accept the connection from iPhone. However, it only works when both of devices are in my home network. It never works out in public networks such as Starbucks or Campus. Since I am not familiar with networking architecture, anyone can explain why the connection is not established in public networks and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some similar issue before. It turned out that the port I was using was actually blocked in that specific network. Try another one. Hope it works.